# In SQL server, how could I select top @num percent in a loop

Tags: sql, variables, loops, select, random

Here is what I am trying to do:

run a loop 3 times; each time i randomly select top 5%, 10%, 15% from the table, respectively. However, in the output table, the column 'Ratio' is 5 for every row and the column name is not 'Ratio. The first column in the output table should show the ratio that is applied, i.e., including 5%, 10%, 15%.  Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT    
DECLARE @endFlag INT 
DECLARE @num INT
DECLARE @totalScen INT
SET @intFlag = 1
SET @endFlag=5
SET @num =5
SET @totalScen =15

WHILE (@num <= @totalScen)
BEGIN
 WHILE (@intFlag <= @endFlag)
 BEGIN

       WITH cte AS (select  t1.gender, t1.age_group

        from
           (
             select * from mytable1
             where caseid not in
             (
              select top (@num)  percent caseid from mytable1

              order by newid()
              ) 

           ) t1
     )
  INSERT INTO newTable
  SELECT @num as Ratio, gender, age_group
  FROM cte

 SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
 END
SET @num=@num+5
END
GO
```

Comment: Are you trying to get 5 results at each ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming based on your question that you want the inner loop to run 5x for each of your ratio values 5,10,15. If that's the case you need to move the variables used in the inner loop to the inner loop:

```
DECLARE  @num INT      = 5
        ,@totalScen INT = 15   
WHILE (@num <= @totalScen)
BEGIN
     DECLARE @intFlag INT = 1
            ,@endFlag INT = 5
     WHILE (@intFlag <= @endFlag)
     BEGIN  
           WITH cte AS (select  t1.gender, t1.age_group
                        from  (select * 
                              from mytable1
                              where caseid not IN (select top (@num)  percent caseid 
                                                   from mytable1
                                                   order by newid()
                                                   )
                              ) t1
                        )
           INSERT INTO newTable
           SELECT @num as Ratio, gender, age_group
           FROM cte
     SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
     END
SET @num=@num+5
END
GO
```

Easy way to test behavior is by printing variables:

```
DECLARE  @num INT      = 5
        ,@totalScen INT = 15
WHILE (@num <= @totalScen)
BEGIN
     DECLARE @intFlag INT = 1
            ,@endFlag INT = 5
     WHILE (@intFlag <= @endFlag)
     BEGIN

     PRINT @num
     PRINT @intflag

     SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
     END
SET @num=@num+5
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from value for inner loop never resetting it self. You have to move

```
    SET @intFlag = 1
    SET @endFlag = 5
```

Inside your outer loop. Like so.

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
   ,@endFlag INT
   ,@num INT
   ,@totalScen INT

SET @num = 5
SET @totalScen = 15

WHILE ( @num <= @totalScen )
    BEGIN
        SET @intFlag = 1
        SET @endFlag = 5
        WHILE ( @intFlag <= @endFlag )
            BEGIN
                PRINT '@intFlag:' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @intFlag)
                SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
            END
        PRINT '@num2:' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @num)
        SET @num = @num + 5
    END
```

Always best to use `PRINT` to see what values your variables are instead of assuming that it is behaving correctly.